# Bookshelf and Knex SQLITE_ERROR: near "(":

Tags: javascript, sqlite, knex.js, bookshelf.js

This is my console and the error it logs. I'm trying to write a script (createDB.js) to populate the database with listings. I'm stumped as to why I'm getting an SQLITE_ERROR.

```
$ backend node createDB.js
listing:  ModelBase {
  attributes:
   { icon: 'pin',
     title: 'Hatsushiba',
     category: 'station',
     lat: 1.213,
     lng: 1.452 },
  _previousAttributes: {},
  changed:
   { icon: 'pin',
     title: 'Hatsushiba',
     category: 'station',
     lat: 1.213,
     lng: 1.452 },
  relations: {},
  cid: 'c1' }
error Error: insert into  (`category`, `created_at`, `icon`, `lat`, `lng`, `title`, `updated_at`) values ('station', '2018-06-28 10:52:27.520', 'pin', 1.213, 1.452, 'Hatsushiba', '2018-06-28 10:52:27.520') - SQLITE_ERROR: near "(": syntax error
```

createDB.js

```
const Listing = require('./model')
const testListing = new Listing()
testListing.set('icon', 'pin')
testListing.set('title', 'Hatsushiba')
testListing.set('category', 'station')
testListing.set('lat', 1.213)
testListing.set('lng', 1.452)

testListing.save().then((listing) => {
  console.log(`saved ${listing.title} yo!`)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(`error ${err}`)
})
```

./migrate/index.js

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('listings', function(table) {
      table.increments('id').primary()
      table.string('icon').defaultTo('pin')
      table.string('title', 128)
      table.string('category')
      table.float('lat')
      table.float('lng')
      table.timestamps()
    })
}

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .dropTable('listings')
}
```

model.js
    const bookshelf = require('./bookshelf')

```
const Listing = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tablename: 'listings',
  hasTimestamps: true
})

module.exports = Listing
```

knexfile.js

```
module.exports = {
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: 'app.db'
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true
}
```

bookshelf.js

```
const path = require('path'),
      fs = require('fs'),
      knex = require('knex')(require('./knexfile'))

module.exports =  require('bookshelf')(knex)
```

Comment: One of the issues is the tablename isn't being included in the SQLite statement... not sure why.

Comment: knex has seed command available.

Answer (score 0):

in model.js

```
const Listing = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tablename: 'listings', <<====== change "tablename" to "tableName" =====<<
  hasTimestamps: true
})

module.exports = Listing
```